# Polarization of gauge boson and gauge choices

Tags: polarization, gauge

Consider the following facts:

1. For a particle with momentum $k$, the two transverse polarization vectors $\epsilon({\bf k}, \lambda_{1})$ and $\epsilon({\bf k}, \lambda_{1})$ are purely spatial and orthogonal to $\bf k$, that is,
   $$\epsilon^{0}({\bf k}, \lambda_{1}) = 0,$$
   $$\epsilon({\bf k}, \lambda_{1})\cdot{k} = 0,$$
   $$\epsilon^{0}({\bf k}, \lambda_{2}) = 0,$$
   $$\epsilon({\bf k}, \lambda_{2})\cdot{k} = 0.$$
2. The third, longitudinal, polarization vector $\epsilon({\bf k}, \lambda_{3})$}, for a particle with momentum $k$, is timelike positive, orthogonal to $k$ as well as the transverse polarization vectors, and has unit negative norm, that is, 
   $$\epsilon^{0}({\bf k}, \lambda_{3}) > 0,$$
   $$\epsilon({\bf k}, \lambda_{3})\cdot{k} = 0,$$
   $$\epsilon({\bf k}, \lambda_{3})\cdot{\epsilon({\bf k}}, \lambda_{1}) = 0,$$
   $$\epsilon({\bf k}, \lambda_{3})\cdot{\epsilon({\bf k}}, \lambda_{2}) = 0,$$
   $$\epsilon({\bf k}, \lambda_{3})\cdot{\epsilon({\bf k}}, \lambda_{3}) = -1.$$
3. We can infer from the orthogonality of the polarization vectors that the longitudinal polarization vector of a particle points in the direction of momentum of the particle.

---

Are these facts true for any gauge choice of the electromagnetic four-vector $A^{\mu}$?

Comment: The question is not clear to me. In general there is plenty of freedom in the definition of the polarisation vectors - there is no canonical way to define them. The conditions you wrote are probably just one choice, as valid as any other. Moreover, the behaviour of these vectors is gauge dependent; they are true vectors in covariant gauges, and they are not in non-covariant gauges. Your choice of $\epsilon^0\equiv0$ probably means that you have the Coulomb gauge in mind, in which case the particle is necessarily massless, and therefore it is not clear what the third vector is supposed to be.

Comment: These polarization vectors for the (massive) W boson are taken from problem 7.3.1 of Cliff Burgess's textbook `The Standard Model: A Primer.' The problem does not explain the motivation for these choices of the polarization vector. I am trying to physically motivate the choices.